# Summarize Tablix on Each Page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 to generate invoices.  The user selects a batch and each invoice in the batch should print out 1 to a page.  Each invoice should contain the summary of charges at the bottom, preferably in the footer to keep a consistent position.

Problem is, it won't allow me to put tables or subreports in the footer.  All I can do is put text boxes, but the only data I can get in there are aggregates pertaining to my dataset as a whole.  I can't get subtotals for just that invoice within the batch.

Basically my setup is a tablix that is grouped by invoice number with a page break between instances of the group.  This ensures each invoice prints to its own page.  But when I try to add a text box to the footer to subtotal THAT invoice, my only option seems to be First(Fields!SubTotal.Value, "DataSet") or some other aggregate.  I need the subtotal for THAT invoice number whether it be the 1st or the 5th.

I don't know if I'm explaining this very well.  I'm sorry if this doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change your approach a little bit:

Instead of adding a subtotal outside of the tablix, add a total to the bottom of the group. Insert additional lines in the group, but outside of the detail(or subgroup) rows that are repeating within the page.

Page footers aren't very tightly connected to the data or its layout, so they will be trickier to keep sub-totals within. If you really need to do it this way, then you'll need to keep a running total in some embedded code in the report. Start with [this example](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/09/running-totals-per-page-in-ssrs-to.html) and add additional code to zero out the running total at the beginning of each page.

Comment: That is how I have it now.  Problem is, there might be 1 line item on an invoice or 50.  So the location of the summary may appear in the middle of the page or the middle of the next page. I am trying for a cleaner look by having appear on the same part of the page each time.

Comment: Makes sense. In that case, I might add a row with dynamic height (based on number of report items in group) or add fake rows to my dataset... I think either of those will be easier than trying to get the right data in the footer. But certainly try the embedded code answer as well.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of changing a blank row's height depending on how many line items, but haven't found the code to do so. Adding blank rows to my data set may work.  I will explore that.  But if you have any examples of code that changes row height on the fly, I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: So I ended up adding enough blank rows to the report to make it hit the "sweet spot" so to speak.  Then changed the visibility of each to show or hide based on the number of rows my data set returned.  Thus ensuring the same number or rows always prints out regardless of how many rows the data set returns the the summary prints to the same spot on the page.  This was kind of a hybrid of your two suggestions so I will accept your answer.  Thanks!